# Convert a c# string with year only (sometimes) to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

The program needs to find the youngest (or oldest) person within a list. The birthday is actually a `string`. I converted the dates using `Convert.ToDateTime()`, which is working fine. However, in a few cases, the input is just a `year`, without the `day` and the `month`, e.g. "1945". The converter fails.

My questions:

1) what checker can I add in order to prevent such a run-time failure?

2) How can I convert it to date, without overriding strings that include the `day` and the `month`? 
the code is:

```
DateTime curr_bday = Convert.ToDateTime(p.Birthday);
```

here is the full routine:

```
public string the_youngest(Persons _p2)
{
    DateTime youngAge = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1005");

    DateTime curr_bday;
    string to_ret = "";

    foreach (var p in _p2.persons)
    {
        curr_bday = Convert.ToDateTime(p.Birthday);
        if (curr_bday < youngAge)
        {
            youngAge = curr_bday;
            to_ret = p.Name + " : " + p.Birthday;
        } 
    }
    return (to_ret);
}
```

Comment: Where are these strings coming from, and can you give us a few examples?

Comment: Test to see if the string is an integer with `int.TryParse`.  If it is, initialize your birthday variable with a newly constructed DateTime where you specify only the year.  Otherwise, parse the string as a date time

Comment: The strings come from a parser. That's a given input.

Comment: @ Flydog57 : it looks like it is working well. I had a bug in the compare part (bigger birhday means younger person) Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore the `TryParse` function. it works with dates, integers, and decimals.

```
DateTime birthdate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(p.Birthday, out birthdate))
{
  //full date here successfully converted
  //continue
}
else
{
   birthdate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(p.Birthday), 1, 1); //1 Jan by default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `TryParse` all over is your best bet:

```
DateTime bDay;
if (int.TryParse(dateString, out var birthYear))
{
    dateString = new DateTime(birthYear, 7, 4); //born on the 4th of July
}
else if (!DateTime.TryParse( dateString, out bDay))
{
    //let the user know there's a problem
}
```

Comment: most stable and concise solution here, have an upvote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the only two possible formats are {year} and {valid datetime} string then you can do

```
DateTime d;
if (p.Birthday.Length <= 4)
{
     int year = int.Parse(p.Birthday);
     d = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
}
else
{
     d = DateTime.Parse(p.Birthday)
}
```

This will work for another 8000 years. However if there are other special case then you need to handle those separately.

Comment: You are better off using `int.TryParse` in the `if` statement.  What about "3/21" (today).  It's four characters, and I believe it would be a valid date in a US copy of Excel